# Do I need to perform Ghusal?

Tags: ghusl, ritual

I don't know why but naturally I got a strong feeling before discharge of semen but at end I could control it. 
Now I can say that I didn't discharge semen and due to pressure I couldn't control urine from being discharged so,
 should I perform Ghusal?

Comment: Can you please fix your grammar. Your question is already complicated and with badly written question, you are making it harder for us to answer it.

Comment: Yes you should. If you feel lust, you should perform ghusl.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, i assume that your question is complex (somewhat), actually I didn't figure it out completely. anyhow, I hope my response be related to your question and can help you (God willing)

**In accordance with the ruling(Fatwa) of Imam Khomeini:**

> The Ghusl is not wajib(mandatory) in case the semen moves from its
>   place and doesn't get out, or you doubt that the semen has gone out or
>   not. But if some water( after a while) gets out from the body and you
>   are sure that is semen (that had moved but didn't get out), leads to
>   the Wajib Ghusl(Jenabah).
>
> (Tozihul-Masaael, Al-Mhshi lel-Imam-Khomeini, Vol.1, Pages 208 & 211)

Of course you can see the link below which consists of another similar issue and it could help you as well.

[www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/ar/archive/question/fa3629) (in Arabic and Farsi)

---

**Source**:

[www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa3351) (in Farsi)